# iOS UIView scrolling UI - how to implement?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

Forgive me to the obtuse title, as I'm unsure how to describe this question.

Recently many iOS apps utilise a scrolling UI design pattern which helps to maximise screen real-estate, typically hiding the header when the user scrolls downwards.

For example, Instragram's main view has the Instragram header at the top. Scrolling upwards on this view keeps the header fixed at the top, and the view bounces back normally to the top of the content. But scroll down and the header acts as part of the content, making way for an extra 44 points of vertical space.

Its probably that I haven't done much iOS work in a while, but I can't easily figure out how best to impliment this? Apologies for the terrible description.

Comment: We did something similar in one of our app where when you scroll a table view, it expands the table to almost full screen if you're not at the top (leaving some space at the top to shrink the table if desired). When you scroll back to the top, the table shrink back down. If I remember correctly, we used a series of setFrame inside [UIView animations], offsetting the Y coordinate of each element. I also remember we had to implement the scrollViewDelegate method and check the scrollView's contentOffset value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried ranReloaded's answer above but it seems that calling `setFrame:` on a UIScrollView stops the view from bouncing when going beyond its bounds.

Instead I set the scroll view to fit inside another UIView called `scrollerWrapper`. Applying the calculated origin and height to this view gives me effect I'm after plus retains the bounce behaviour.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*) scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    CGRect headerFrame = header.frame;
    CGRect wrapperFrame = scrollerWrapper.frame;

    if(offset.y > 0){
        headerFrame.origin.y = -offset.y;
        wrapperFrame.origin.y = MAX(0, headerFrame.size.height - offset.y);
        }
    else{
        headerFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
        wrapperFrame.origin.y = headerFrame.size.height;
        }
   wrapperFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - wrapperFrame.origin.y;

    [header setFrame:headerFrame];
    [scrollerWrapper setFrame:wrapperFrame];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why setting the frame of the header view would affect the scroll view; header and scroll are independent siblings (not parent-child)

Comment: Why do you need to modify the scroll view's frame? Perhaps I didn't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If the header stays put no matter what, use a separate view on top of the scroll view. 
If you use UITableView, you can use section headers.

**EDIT** Use this code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*) scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    CGRect headerFrame = _headerView.frame;

    if(offset.y > 0){
        headerFrame.origin.y = offset.y;
    }
    else{
        headerFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
    }

    [_headerView setFrame:headerFrame];
}
```

(Assumes _headerView is your header, sitting on top of the scroll view, not inside it. Also, both scroll view and header begin at the top of their parent view, y==0. Also, **your view controller must be set up as delegate of the scroll view**)

I just wrote this code from memory; haven't tested it but at most it should only need tweaking.

Comment: That's the thing; the header is fixed in the upwards scroll direction, but is movable on the downwards direction.

Comment: If that is the case, either: 1) use a table view with one section and one big cell (not very elegant) or 2) Adjust your separate header view based on the current scroll offset obtainesd in the UIScrollView delegate methods (requires more work but is better)

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot later today.

Comment: I did have to adjust your code a bit, see answer below. Thx for shove in the right direction.